# How to update azure app registrations app property?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Updating app service in Microsoft azure app enterprise application doesn't reflect the changes in App Registration.

1. Add owner in the app service under Enterprise application
2. Check the App registration and go to app service then the owners didn't update the list
   Tried to restart the app service but it doesn't work.

Expectation: can be able to modify access permission under app registration

Result: Some actions may be disabled due to your permissions. To request access, contact the application owner(s) or your administrator.

Comment: The enterprise application is different from app registration, if you want to add `Owner` to app registration, why not add it directly in the app registration -> select your app -> `Owners`?

Comment: What do you mean `app service under Enterprise application` and `access permission under app registration`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description/definition of an app (listed under "App registrations") and the instance of an app in an Azure AD tenant (listed under "Enterprise apps") are modeled as two separate things which can be controlled independently [see note 1]. A user can be made owner of one and not the other, or of both.

In a typical use case, the *app developer* is made owner of the app under "App registrations". This user can mange the app's credentials and redirect URLs, change which permissions the app *asks for* (but not which permissions it is *granted*), *define* the app's roles (but not *assign* users/groups to these roles), etc. The *app's business owner* in a given tenant (remember that one app can be used in many different tenants, by many different organizations) is made owner of the app under "Enterprise apps". This user can control access to the app, assign users and groups to roles in the app, etc.

It sounds like in your case, the same user is taking on both roles. In this case, you would simply make that user owner in both "App registrations" and "Enterprise apps".

Note: Under the covers, an "app registration" corresponds to an *Application* object, and an "enterprise app" corresponds to a *ServicePrincipal* object. This is how it's represented in Azure AD PowerShell, Azure AD Graph API, and the Microsoft Graph API (beta). For a given app which is registered in your tenant, doing `Get-AzureADApplication` will return the "app registration", while `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` will return the "enterprise app". Similarly, `Get-AzureADApplicationOwner` will return the owners of the app registration, and `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner` will return the owners of the enterprise app.

Comment: Good thing you explain that, does this mean I need to ask the global administrator to set me as the owner of the app under App Registration? 
Because I need to set the web app to "User Assignment" to be able to restrict the site and can access only by the group that I assigned to it.

Comment: No, for that setting (which applies to the app's *instance* in your tenant), you need to be made owner of the app under Enterprise apps (i.e. owner of the ServicePrincipal object).

Comment: I'm already owner of the web app under Enterprise apps but can't see my name under App registration. That is what I need to be able to grant admin consent for the AAD graph in apps registration.

Comment: In your first comment, you asked about enabling "require user assignment". For that, you need to be owner under Enterprise apps. To grant admin consent you need to be an admin--being owner of the app won't help you in that case.

Comment: That will make sense now, thank you for explaining all the above. My site finally working now I asked our admin to grant the consent on "App Registration".